# my list view is not selectable

Tags: android, listview

hi i make this tutorial http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html

but i can't select thi item in the listview..

how can i resolve this??

i don'y understand the comments on the blog..

maybe the problem are in here

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView_addConta);
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(Contas.this);      
    db.open();      
    List<Conta> listOfConta = db.getContas();        
    ContaAdapter adapter = new ContaAdapter(this, listOfConta);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`, and override the `onListItemClick` method. This way works best for me.

This is a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html